# Parsing issue with MySQL Query

Tags: php, mysql, sql, function, error-handling

I'm trying to echo some query but it keeps giving me

> Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '}', expecting ',' or ';' in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\test\users.inc.php on line 19

```
<?php
require 'connect.inc.php';

function user_list(){
    $user_list = array();
    $users_query = mysql_query("SELECT `user` FROM `20s` WHERE `online`=1 ");

    while ($users_row = mysql_fetch_assoc($users_query)) {
        $user_list[] = $users_row['user'];

        echo $user_list
    }

}
user_list();
?>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You forgot to add a semicolon here

```
 echo $user_list; 
                ^//<---- Add one here
```